# Converting list of lists into org-table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, clisp

I have a lisp data (list of lists)

```
(setf *table-data*
   '((1 "Team1"
        (("member 1" "data1")
         ("member 2" "data2")
         ("member 3" "data3")))
     (2 "Team2"
        (("member 1" "data1")
         ("member 2" "data2")
         ("member 3" "data3")))))
```

When I try to convert this list into `org-table`, using `(princ *table-data*)` I am getting the output,

```
| 1 | Team1 | ((member 1 data1) (member 2 data2) (member 3 data3)) |
| 2 | Team2 | ((member 1 data1) (member 2 data2) (member 3 data3)) |
```

`org-table` is considering only the outer most list elements.

But I would like to get the output as:

```
| 1 | Team1 | member 1 | data1 |
|   |       | member 2 | data2 |
|   |       | member 3 | data3 |
| 2 | Team2 | member 1 | data1 |
|   |       | member 2 | data2 |
|   |       | member 3 | data3 |
```

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Also, I want to convert back this table into a list of lists instead of plain lists.

Comment: @Drew, though it looks like elisp, actually I am working on **clisp** using **sbcl**.

Comment: Thanks; I restored tag `clisp`.

Answer (score 2):

[Partial answer only: this answer deals with the translation of a table from a lisp data structure as Org mode does it.]

The lisp representation of the table that you want to produce is as follows:

```el
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq x '((1 "Team1" "member 1" "data1")
          ("" ""     "member 2" "data2")
          ("" ""     "member 3" "data3")
          (2 "Team2" "member 1" "data1")
          ("" ""     "member 2" "data2")
          ("" ""     "member 3" "data3")))
x
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| 1 | Team1 | member 1 | data1 |
|   |       | member 2 | data2 |
|   |       | member 3 | data3 |
| 2 | Team2 | member 1 | data1 |
|   |       | member 2 | data2 |
|   |       | member 3 | data3 |
```

as you can see by evaluating the source block.

What remains to be done is to translate from your desired representation to this representation and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks.  I have achieved this.  When I converted from **org-table** to list, I got this answer. The problem is that I have two unnecessary `""` for the first and second columns where there are no elements in the table.  I have to manually edit this list structure to make it a list of list for my purpose.

Comment: That's correct: you have to write a function that converts from your representation to the one that Org mode wants (adding the empty strings in the appropriate places). Then you write another function that converts from the Org mode representation to the one you want (deleting the empty strings). Sometimes people refer to this kind of conversion functions as "impedance matching", using an electronics analogy.

Comment: Like the term **impedance matching.**